# How to set umlaut for header in QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, unicode, diacritics, qtablewidget, qstring

I have this command to set label for all headers of a table:

```
ui.mytable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << tr("VERTRAG") << tr("DATUM/UHRZEIT") << tr("PRÜFER"));
```

But this `Ü` does not appear. I tried to use

```
ui.mytable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << tr("VERTRAG") << tr("DATUM/UHRZEIT") << tr("PRÜFER").replace(QString::fromLatin1("Ü"), "&Uuml;"));
```

and

```
ui.mytable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << tr("VERTRAG") << tr("DATUM/UHRZEIT") << tr("PRÜFER").replace(QString::fromUtf8("Ü"), "&Uuml;"));
```

but it does not work also. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: You can display an image of what you get as I have tested it on Linux with Qt 5.8 and I have not had any problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I updated my result above, I use Qt 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, thank you guys. I have a simple answer. It works with me.

`ui.mytable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << tr("VERTRAG") << tr("DATUM/UHRZEIT") << QLatin1String("PRÜFER"));`

Comment: You should accept your answer, so everyone knows the problem is solved.